# Bootstrap v5.0 'container-lg' is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a webpage using Bootstrap. I am using `.container-lg` so that the content get 100% width when max-width is 767px. But is it not getting 100% width on screens with width less than 768px.

My Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Module 09 - Panda Ecommerce usign Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- My Custom CSS Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-lg">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Panda-ECommerce-Logo">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#home">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#shoes">Shoes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#backpack">Backpack</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript CDN-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

How to fix this problem?

How can I get 100% width on screens less than 768px?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Bootstrap we have this CSS style:

```
.container, .container-fluid, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: var(--bs-gutter-x,.75rem);
    padding-left: var(--bs-gutter-x,.75rem);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
```

for getting 100% width you should remove the padding, so you should use **padding: 0** in your CSS style
I hope this solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this with the code below (SASS) so we can keep the padding.

```
/* Fix for bootstrap container */
.container-lg{
  @include media-breakpoint-down(lg){
    width: auto;
  }
}
```